# PHP Script adding two rows to one table

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

The following code is adding a blank row to the "autos" table.

```
<? 
$Status = $_POST['Status'];
///All other variables are the same, just removed to make it more succinct ?>

<? include('../include/db-connect.php');

 /////////////// LOOKS FOR DUPLICATE STOCK NUMBERS ///////////////
$check_stock = "SELECT * FROM autos WHERE StockNumber='$StockNumber'";
$checking_stock = mysql_query($check_stock);
if( mysql_num_rows($checking_stock) > 0 ) {echo "<p>Sorry, a vehicle with this Stock Number already exists. Please <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Go Back</a> and try again.</p>";} 

/////////////// WRITE CAR TO DB ///////////////
  else {      

    //vehicle basics  
    $adding_vehicle = "INSERT INTO autos VALUES 
('$Status',
 '$StockNumber',
 '$VIN',
 '$Year',
 '$Make',
 '$Model',
 '$Colour',
 '$KM',
 '$PurchaseDate',
 '$Seller',
 '$PurchasePrice',
 '$Creator',
 '$Today',
 '')";
mysql_query($adding_vehicle);   
    //extended info
$add_ext = "INSERT INTO autos_notes VALUES ('$StockNumber', '$TrimLevel', '$Transmission', '$ListPrice', '$Notes', '$Disclosures', '')";
mysql_query($add_ext);  

/////////////// UPLOADS FILES ///////////////

//E-TEST
 $target = "e-test/"; 
 $target= $target. $StockNumber .'/'; 

 if (!mkdir($target, 0777, true)) {
}
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['etest_pdf']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['etest_pdf']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 
$file_type = "E-Test";
$etest_add = "INSERT INTO upload_changes VALUES ('$Type', '$StockNumber', '$file_type', '$Etest', '')";
mysql_query($etest_add);     
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['etest_pdf']['name']). " has been uploaded.<br>";
 } 
 else {
 echo "No e-test file was uploaded.<br/>";
 } 
//CARPROOF
 $target_cp = "carproof/";
 $target_cp= $target_cp. $StockNumber .'/'; 

 if (!mkdir($target_cp, 0777, true)) {
} 
 $target_cp = $target_cp . basename( $_FILES['carproof_pdf']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['carproof_pdf']['tmp_name'], $target_cp)) 
 {
$file_type = "CarProof";
$cp_add = "INSERT INTO upload_changes VALUES ('$Type', '$StockNumber', '$file_type', '$CarProof', '')";
mysql_query($cp_add);    
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['carproof_pdf']['name']). " has been uploaded.<br>";
 } 
 else {
 echo "No CarProof Added.<br/>";
 } 

 //PURCHASE ORDER
 $target_po = "purchases/";
 $target_po= $target_po. $StockNumber .'/'; 

 if (!mkdir($target_po, 0777, true)) {
} 
 $target_po = $target_po . basename( $_FILES['purchase_order']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['purchase_order']['tmp_name'], $target_po)) 
 {
$file_type = "Purchase Order";
$po_add = "INSERT INTO upload_changes VALUES ('$Type', '$StockNumber', '$file_type', '$purchase_order', '')";
mysql_query($po_add);    
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['purchase_order']['name']). " has been uploaded.<br>";
 } 
 else {
 echo "No Purchase Order Added.<br/>";
 } 
?>
```

It's only the inserts into the "autos" table that are doing this, but I included the rest of the code to see if there's something I missed. I've changed the name of the $adding_vehicle variable, so it's definitely not being called more than once. The last field is an auto_increment.

Thanks in advance! I'm knew to this so I'm sure the code could use some work.

Comment: Sidenote: `$StockNumber` seems to be undefined.

Comment: When in development, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: It is defined, I just commented out all my variables so you weren't seeing wasted lines of code.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I have my errors showing and there are none.

Comment: I understand. That's why I phrased it that way ;-) what's the error message you're getting?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not getting any error messages. I'm just getting a blank line in my autos table.

Comment: The only thing I can see that would equal a blank entry is the `''` in `'$Today',
 ''`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, that's why I'm confused. Because the '' is my auto_increment field.

Comment: If it's auto, then just remove it, you don't need it.

Comment: If I remove the quotes it doesn't add my row.

Comment: Try moving the `''` here instead as the first value `'', '$Status',`

Comment: Nope, no go. Won't add anything

Comment: try being explicit with the names of the columns you're adding to?

Comment: i.e. insert into autos (col1,col2,etc) values ($status,$stock,etc)

Comment: @a7omiton Thanks for the reply... Still inserts a blank row after the data.

Comment: The only thing I can think of at this point is to double check all of your form's elements making sure there are no typos and that the amount of VALUE variables match your form's elements.

Comment: are you using the auto tables auto_implement field as a foreign key for auto_notes?

Comment: No, they both have their own unique ID using auto_increment

Comment: did u include the ID field when you tried what i said? you shouldn't do that because its auto_increment. the only other thing i would try is instead of including your db connect script, do include_once or require_once. sorry im not much help

Comment: @a7omiton I did include the ID, so I just tried it without and that didn't work. Then I tried to do include once or require once and neither changed things... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm thinking it may be an issue with my Database setup rather than my code.

Answer (score 0):

Please, verify if your form method is POST otherwise the superglobal $_POST is not populated.

Debug or make a `print_r($_POST)` just to verify if the array is populated, the superglobal
`$_REQUEST` is also populated with POST values.
  Your autos table should have a primary key ( say stocknumber or VIN plus model) so no duplicate or empty values are inserted. You should also filter and validate data before inserting them.

Comment: My form method is post and the array is being populated. This method adds my data but also adds a blank row. I the last field as an auto_incremented primary key.